# How to install dos2unix on Linux without root access?

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user

`$uname -a`

`Linux vm-** 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 25 19:24:22 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I downloaded dos2unix-7.3.3-win32.zip and unzipped it. 
Under bin folder from the unzipped file, I got dos2unix.exe

How to install dos2unix in Linux?

I can't do `yum install dos2unix` as I am not & can't get root access.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other answers show how to download and compile `dos2unix`, but if you're simply looking to convert files from DOS-style line endings (CR-LF) to Unix-style line endings, there are several other approaches which shouldn't involve installing anything:

- if you have `tr`:

  ```
  tr -d '\r' < input > output
  ```
- if you have Perl:

  ```
  perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input
  ```

  (which converts the file in-place, same as `dos2unix`)
- if you have `sed`:

  ```
  sed -i 's/^M$//' input
  ```

  where you'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to get `^M`.

Comment: +1. I have many files in my directory. I am executing `find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`  In your example for `tr` and `sed`, how can I achieve for many files?

Comment: I wouldn't use the `tr` version in that case, but with `sed`, `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/^M$//' {} \;` should work. Better still, `find . -type f -print 0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/^M$//'`, which will process as many files as possible each time it runs `sed`.

Comment: And if you don't need to process files in subdirectories, `sed -i 's/^M$//' *` would work just as well.

Comment: In my input file I have 2 records. Both the records contain `^M` character. When i run `sed -i 's/^M$//' input > output` , my `output` file is containing 0 records. I think `sed` is removing the record which contains `^M`. Instead I want the record to be retained, but only remove `^M`.

Comment: I just found out `sed -i 's/\r//' *` works. Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, that's fine; the `^M` above stands for Ctrl-V and Ctrl-M, not literal `^` and `M`. (As you found out, `^M$` as such matches lines containing only `M`.) `\r` support is possibly a GNU extension, I'd have to check.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you downloaded a dos2unix executable *for windows* (dos2unix-7.3.3-**win32**.zip), which is not what you want because you are using Linux.

Try downloading the source code for dos2unix for Linux and extract it to your home dir:

```
mkdir $HOME/bin/
tar -zxvf dos2unix-7.3.3-src.tar.gz # the exact name of the downloaded file may vary
cd dos2unix-7.3.3
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/
make
make install
```

if everything goes well you will be able to find a dos2unix file somewhere in your **$HOME/bin** directory.
you can use this new installation by typing

```
$ ~/bin/dos2unix windows_formatted_file.txt
```

Comment: how to install make w/o sudo... :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the source code and compile it.

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/postdownload?source=dlp) is the source code.

To untar it execute: (VERSION equals to the version you have downloaded)

```
tar xvf dos2unix-VERSION.tar.gz
```

Finaly execute:

```
make
```

If the compilation succeeded, it will appear an executable called dos2unix and unix2dos.

Answer (score 1):

Download dos2unix-7.3.3.tar.gz.

```
tar xvzf dos2unix-7.3.3.tar.gz
cd dos2unix-7.3.3
make install prefix=$HOME
```

This will install dos2unix in $HOME/bin/.

For further information see INSTALL.txt.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the specific RPM from the OS website. For example, for CentOS, download the RPM file from http://vault.centos.org/